# MVC 4 and RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in my view which is displayed based upon a bool property on the model. All works well, however I have noticed that if a user uses the back button on the browser the partial view which was previously displayed is no longer shown.

Can anyone shed light on way this is happening?

Comment: Assign a TempData["boolValue"] from your controller instead of using bool property in model. Use TempData["boolValue"] to display the PartialView

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the reason that when we press browser back button , the request does't go to the controller , and brower return view of previous page so we have model with unfilled fields ( empty model ) , thats why this is happening , you can use TempData["yourvalue"] , so that it sticked with the page.Thanks